# Are all integral domains in which all irreducible elements are prime G.C.D domains?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, factoring, gcd-and-lcm

I know that in G.C.D domains all irreducible elements are prime.  Does the converse of this statement hold?  If not, is there a weaker condition than being a G.C.D. domain that is both sufficient and necessary for all irreducibles being prime?